# RAR archive files yield incomplete extraction results

Tags: size, rar

I am trying to extract a `muli-part` rar archive. When I extract the very first file of the archive, several different folders get created and in some of them not any files exist.
I viewed all the `rar` archive contents by: `unrar l filename_n.rar`, and for the very last one of them, the output was something like the following lines:

```
 Attributes      Size     Date    Time   Name
----------- ---------  ---------- -----  ----
*   ..A....  38007775  2017-06-12 02:08  32 xxx-xxxxx-xx
*   ..A....  27291830  2017-06-12 02:08  33 xxx-xxxxx-xx
*   ..A....       519  2017-06-12 02:08  33 xxx-xxxxx-xx
*   ..A....  45289788  2017-06-12 02:08  33 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  27 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  27 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  27 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  27 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  31 xxx-xxxxx-xx
    ...D...         0  1979-11-30 00:00  33 xxx-xxxxx-xx
```

I want to know what each of the attributes (A, D) mean in the output and why some of the files have the size of `0` when there is a name existing for them and why they don't result in any file after extraction.

Comment: There is also something strange about the `date` as I just noticed. Are these files damaged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [FAT-style attributes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#attributes). `A` means “archive”, and is used to track files that need to be backed up. `D` means directory, which also explains why the entries have a zero size.

As far as the strange dates and times go, as I understand the [RAR technote](http://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm), directory entries don’t necessarily even have an associated timestamp; this might be what’s going on here (November 30, 1979 at midnight looks like a default timestamp to me).

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried: `rar lb archive.rar`, and as I see there are no files available in some of the directories mentioned above (in my `rar` file). Thank you very very much again for your help.